# PHP 5.4: How do I use shorthand array syntax for multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php

```
$ar = [
    array('select' => 'ven_id, ven_name'),
    array('conditions' => array(
        ['col=?', $value],
        ['col=?', $value]
    ))
];
```

The above code  is halfway there! How do i alter this so that the nested arrays also use shorthand?

Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `array(` with `[` and `)` with `]`.. it's really not a question material.

Comment: For anyone else who just went "Huh? PHP allows you to use that syntax?", it's an added feature in PHP 5.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace `array()` with `[]`:

```
$ar = [
    ['select' => 'ven_id, ven_name'],
    ['conditions' => [
        ['col=?', $value],
        ['col=?', $value]
    ]]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I maybe missing something here but why not using the following code (as you already using `[]`):

```
<?php

$ar = [
    ['select' => 'ven_id, ven_name'],
    ['conditions' => [
        ['col=?', $value],
        ['col=?', $value]
    ]],
];

var_dump($ar);
```

Can be tested [here](http://eval.in/32919)

Comment: @VinothBabu Do you mean that I had copied the other answer?! No, I didn't. I would never do that! I'm still using PHP5.3 and was interested if this is really a problem, so I decided to check this using `http://eval.in` .. The fact that the code looks the same is because there is no other way. Note that both answers were given at almost the same time.

Comment: hey cool Man. Just fun. I just checked both answer and got the word copycat in my mind. Cool i will vvote for you man. :)

Comment: ok. you should always assume good faith unless it is totally clear that it is not good faith.. ;)

Comment: can i have your gmail id so we can be in contact for sharing knowledge. just as friends?

Comment: Sorry I will not do that (here on stackoverflow). If you want to contact me, you should check my [homepage](http://metashock.net).